# What is the type should I use for dynamodb stream event in typescript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

When I receive an dynamodb stream event in typescript, I see below schema:

```
Records: [
    {
      eventID: '78dfd1ba7a17adde3cbc987e5af92f91',
      eventName: 'INSERT',
      eventVersion: '1.1',
      eventSource: 'aws:dynamodb',
      awsRegion: 'ap-southeast-2',
      dynamodb: [
        {
                    "id": {
                        "S": "xxx"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "S": "xxx"
                    }
                },
                "NewImage": {
                  ...
                },
                "OldImage": { ... }
      ],
      eventSourceARN: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:115136697128:table/joeyDevices/stream/2020-07-10T04:42:54.695'
    }
]
```

Is there a type definition I can use for this event in typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an addendum to the already accepted answer

```
// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_StreamRecord.html
export interface StreamRecord<T> {
    ApproximateCreationDateTime?: number;
    Keys?: { [key: string]: AttributeValue };
    NewImage?: T;
    OldImage?: T;
    SequenceNumber?: string;
    SizeBytes?: number;
    StreamViewType?: 'KEYS_ONLY' | 'NEW_IMAGE' | 'OLD_IMAGE' | 'NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES';
}

// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html
export interface DynamoDBRecord<T> {
    awsRegion?: string;
    dynamodb?: StreamRecord<T>;
    eventID?: string;
    eventName?: 'INSERT' | 'MODIFY' | 'REMOVE';
    eventSource?: string;
    eventSourceARN?: string;
    eventVersion?: string;
    userIdentity?: any;
}

// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-ddb-update
export interface DynamoDBStreamEvent<T> {
    Records: DynamoDBRecord<T>[];
}
```

You should extend it with your own type if you are implementing in your own project.

Comment: Looks good, why not making a PR on aws-lambda project?

Comment: Good point @ThomasP1988 :D - might do that one weekend

Answer (score 20):

> Is there a type definition I can use for this event in typescript?

If you are using an AWS Lambda to process dynamo stream events, you can find type definitions in the `@types/aws-lambda` package.

```typescript
import { DynamoDBStreamEvent } from "aws-lambda";
```

You can see the full type definition here in [the github repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/dynamodb-stream.d.ts) for @types/aws-lambda.

```typescript
// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_StreamRecord.html
export interface StreamRecord {
    ApproximateCreationDateTime?: number;
    Keys?: { [key: string]: AttributeValue };
    NewImage?: { [key: string]: AttributeValue };
    OldImage?: { [key: string]: AttributeValue };
    SequenceNumber?: string;
    SizeBytes?: number;
    StreamViewType?: 'KEYS_ONLY' | 'NEW_IMAGE' | 'OLD_IMAGE' | 'NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES';
}

// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html
export interface DynamoDBRecord {
    awsRegion?: string;
    dynamodb?: StreamRecord;
    eventID?: string;
    eventName?: 'INSERT' | 'MODIFY' | 'REMOVE';
    eventSource?: string;
    eventSourceARN?: string;
    eventVersion?: string;
    userIdentity?: any;
}

// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-ddb-update
export interface DynamoDBStreamEvent {
    Records: DynamoDBRecord[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can use [AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property) to unmarshall DynamoDB's persisted form into an object.

[Amazon DynamoDB DataMapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper) takes advantage of `@aws/dynamodb-data-marshaller` and `@aws/dynamodb-expressions` packages and allows easy interoperability between your application's domain classes and their persisted form in Amazon DynamoDB. Your job is to create the relevant application class and to add properties to the prototype of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found another library https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-data-marshaller/ which looks similar as the one you posted. This library is also from AWS github. I am not sure why they release two libraries to do one thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v3 sdk then you can just do this:

```
import type { _Record } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb-streams'



Records: _Rocord[]
```